# Reference to a C pointer from Assembler

Tags: assembly, arm, gnu-assembler

I want to reference a c pointer in an assembler function. In C the declaration is as follows:

> const uint32_t *SERCOM0_SPI_DATA_REG_ADDR = (volatile uint32_t *) &(SERCOM0->SPI.DATA.reg); //  uint32_t reg;

In assem the pointer address(0x40003028) is correctly shown in the debugger. With the following code I want to write the value 0x1f to the spi register which is uint32_t.

```
// reg uint32_t sercom spi data
    ldr r0, =SERCOM0_SPI_DATA_REG_ADDR
    ldrb r1,=#0x1f
    str r1, [r0]
```

If I now look at the register r0 the value is not 0x40003028 but 0x20000F8C. Therefore at the address is not the value 0x1f written.

In the disassembly window :

```
    44:     ldr r0, =SERCOM0_SPI_DATA_REG_ADDR
00007804   ldr  r0, [pc, #28]        
    45:     ldrb r1,= #0x1f // SERCOM0_SPI_DATA_SYNC_DATA
00007806   mov.w    r1, #31      
    46:     str r1, [r0]
```

The assem file is like this:

```
.section .ram
.syntax unified
.cpu cortex-m4
.thumb

.space 0xe4
.data
.text
.align 4

.type SEND_DATA, %function
.global SEND_DATA

VUSB_SEND_DATA:
...
bx lr
```

Answer (score 1):

Recall that symbols in assembly are the *addresses* of variables they represent.  So

```
ldr r0, =SERCOM0_SPI_DATA_REG_ADDR
```

loads `r0` with the address of `SERCOM0_SPI_DATA_REG_ADDR`, roughly being equal to

```
r0 = &SERCOM0_SPI_DATA_REG_ADDR;
```

To load the *value* of that variable, you need to dereference the pointer you have just obtained:

```
ldr r0, =SERCOM0_SPI_DATA_REG_ADDR    @ load address of variable
ldr r0, [r0]                          @ load value of variable
```

Combine this with your remaining code, this should fix your issues.  Note that for better code size, I recommend to use `movs` explicitly when loading small constants on thumb targets.

```
ldr r0, =SERCOM0_SPI_DATA_REG_ADDR
ldr r0, [r0]
movs r1, #0x1f
str r1, [r0]
```

This should yield the desired result.

Comment: Tnx, then I write the address directly because this cost me one ldr. Is this right or what can I do that I need only 3 instructions?

Comment: You can do that, that'll reduce it down to three instructions.  But again, why not let the C compiler do that for you?  Note that if you have multiple registers in the same address region you can use an indexed addressing mode to avoid having to reload the address again and again.

Comment: Yes, good idea but I have not the knowledge to do it. Can you give an example? I hope you dont mean that I write it in C. With pure c we have another problem. We must write it in asm because of the optimization.

Comment: @makurisan.  No, you do not need to write it in asm “because of the optimisation.”  Optimisation only “breaks” your code because your code is incorrect.  If you write correct C code, the optimiser is not going to break it.  You are obviously way over your head with trying to write parts of your code in assembly.  This approach is not going to lead anywhere useful.  Your time would be spent much better by actually fixing your C code so it's not defective.

Comment: You have now spent three or four questions wasting everyones time by asking people to fix wildly incorrect assembly code that could be replaced by extremely straightforward C code.  Either learn how to program in assembly or learn how to write correct C code, but your current approach is not going to work out.

Comment: I mean it's funny that you insist that the C compiler breaks your C code, yet you haven't asked a single question about that.  Instead you went right down the alley of “huch, so the C compiler does something I don't understand.  Guess we must write assembly then.”  This is pretty much the definition of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Go fix your underlying problem (wrong C code) instead of trying to chase an assembly implementation.

Comment: Okay, the c compiler is great and also great in optimization but. If you optimize with the compiler, it sets a lot of statements at the beginning of the function. This leads to time because I want optimization but at the beginning of the function I must do something immediately. This is the reason and we spent a lot of time with volatile do optimize something out in pure c. We speak about ns and btw the pure c code is running.

Comment: @makurisan Then ask a question about achieving this instead of asking questions about your solution attempts.  This is going to be a lot more productive.

Comment: No, I dont. We have deceided to do it with asm because of other things. I can not explain all but at the moment I consist in asm. I have not a problem with my question and you helped me already. Thank you about that.

Comment: @makurisan Okay then.  I mean that approach can work.  I'm sorry for letting my frustration out at you.  Fundamentally, there is no one-size-fits-'em-all type solution for optimal assembly code and ARM thumb doesn't exactly lend itself to solutions with a minimal amount of instructions.  There may be ways to avoid some of the constant and address generating loads, but it's quite hard to say without seeing the big picture.

Comment: Yes, it works with pure assembler now and this is better because we can better debug the functions. This asm code is only 30ns slower now than an older code witth inline asm.